# f(x) is invertible polynomial function of degree ‘n’ {n≥3} then f"(x) = 0 has exactly ‘n – 2’ distinct real roots if

Tags: polynomials

> $f(x)$ is invertible polynomial function of degree $n\geq 3$ then $f''(x) = 0$ has exactly $n - 2$ distinct real roots if
>
> A)$f′(x)=0$ has $(n−1)/2$ distinct real roots
>
> B)$f′(x)=0$ has $n−1$ distinct real roots
>
> C)all the roots of $f′(x)=0$ are distinct
>
> D)none of these

Comment: Because f(x) is invertible function so all the roots of equation f'(x) = 0 are also the roots of equation f"(x) = 0

⇒  If f'(x) = 0 has  n−12  roots then number of roots of f"(x) = 0 equal to  n−12+(n−12−1) 

=n−2

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has had three years to bring it up to standards.